# Deep learning code to classify whether an image is an apple or not (2 classification). (python)

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, classification

I am a beginner who started studying deep learning.

I want to write deep learning code that can classify whether an image is an apple or not.

1. I have images of fruits such as apples, tomatoes, watermelons, oranges, etc.
2. I want to distinguish only whether it is an apple or not. (2 classification)
3. I want to conclude that tomatoes, watermelons, oranges and other images are 'not apples'.

Is there a similar example?
thanks.

Comment: You are dealing with a binary classification problem. You can use PyTorch. First, you can create a `Dataset` class specifying how to get one training sample together with the transforms (see `torchvision.transforms`) if you need any. Then, you can wrap this class with a `DataLoader` to enable batching etc. Then, you need to write a class defining your model, like CNN/Fully_connected layers, activation functions etc. Then, you can use `BCELoss` as the criterion and start a training loop. See the example https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of such, what you are doing is most often called binary classification (as it either is of the class or not).

Here you can read of a Keras implementation which is quite extensive.
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

If you rather have a minimal working example you could check this out, which seems quite straight forward:
https://medium.com/techiepedia/binary-image-classifier-cnn-using-tensorflow-a3f5d6746697